# ConcurrentModificationException on JPA hibernate save spring/JPA/Java

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are two entities

1.Locker(child)(@OneToMany(mappedBy))

2.Subjects(parent/owner)(@ManyToOne)

Through postman i am passing the Locker entity id and through this i am accessing the Subjects and trying to update a particular thing but i am getting the error and i am not even creating new i am just updating it and  everything is working insertion and deletion except this case

```
@Entity
public class Locker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String lockerno;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="lockey",cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Subjects> subjects;

    //getters andsetter and constructors
```

2nd entity

```
@Entity
public class Subjects {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String subname;
    private String marks;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Locker lockey;

    //getters and setter constructors
```

and now repository interfaces

```
public interface LockerRepo extends CrudRepository<Locker,Integer>{
}

public interface SubjectsRepo2 extends CrudRepository<Subjects,Integer>{
}
```

and now the controller method

```
public String m25(@RequestParam("id") int id) throws Exception {

    Optional<Locker> lock=lockerrepo.findById(id);
    Locker ll=lock.get();
    ArrayList<Subjects> sub=new ArrayList<> (ll.getSubjects());

    Iterator itr=sub.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Subjects sub1=(Subjects) itr.next();
        System.out.println(sub1.getId());
        if(sub1.getId()==3) {
            sub1.setMarks("91");
            subrepo.save(sub1);     
        }
    }
    return "updation done man";
}
```

I am passing the id which is already present in the database but still it is giving this error

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

stack trace

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:850) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at com.example.demo.controller.MainController.m23(MainController.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: The stacktrace says `m23`. You have provided `m25`.

Comment: yes same code and different method name its the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things to note here.

- First, You are using an iterator and trying to modify the object
  contents and save them. Use ListIterator which allows setting
  modified values back to the list.
- Second, you are using `JPA` `save`    inside a loop. Use
  `saveAndFlush` so that hibernate won't persist    object information.

Your code will typically look as specified below:

```
public String m25(@RequestParam("id") int id) throws Exception {
        Optional<Locker> lock=lockerrepo.findById(id);
        Locker ll=lock.get();
        ArrayList<Subjects> sub=new ArrayList<> (ll.getSubjects());
        ListIterator itr=sub.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Subjects sub1=(Subjects) itr.next();
            System.out.println(sub1.getId());
            if(sub1.getId()==3) {
                sub1.setMarks("91");
                itr.set(sub1);
                subrepo.saveAndFlush(sub1);
            }
        }
        return "updation done man";
    }
```

Comment: @RajatAgrawal which implementation solved the issue?

Comment: your solution contains clean code plus you have explained it in a good way also 

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: best apps have this type of returns.
Thanks for sharing, helped me to solve something similar

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the underlying collection that you are iterating while also modifying the value of an object you're iterating over that is part of the same collection, which is causing your ConcurrentModificationException.

See the line in your stack trace:

at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]

and you're using and ArrayList.

Try the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++) { Subjects sub 1= sub.get(0); 
    if(sub1.getId() == 3)
    {...}
```

Comment: hey i tried this thing but still it is giving error(same) and also tried this with List

Comment: Okay, I actually tried to reproduce this locally but can't. Can you just not use the iterator so then and that should solve the issue. for(int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++) { Subjects sub 1= sub.get(0); if(sub1.getId() == 3){...}

Comment: hey yes man if i use for loop instead of iterator still it is working thanks @Rob Scully